# What is a better way to keep "user online"?

Tags: mysql, scalability

I'm working on software for social network and I plan it to scale a lot. Actually, I'm updating `timestamp` column every time user clicks, to be sure they're marked as online. When they do not click for 30 seconds, they're marked as offline. So simply, my queries are

```
UPDATE Users SET timestamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP WHERE uid = 1; -- UNIX_TIEMSTAMP is current unix timestamp given by PHP's time()
SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE timestamp > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP - 30); -- (UNIX_TIMESTAMP - 30) is given directly by PHP (time() - 30)
```

In this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8739/2203), answerer said that

> Will you be updating this table continuously? I doubt that would scale

is there a better way to update user's online status that would scale? Or do you think this is fine?

Comment: I think it would be better, though more complicated, to store the last time a user was active in your caching layer and only periodically write that time to the database.  For starters this should get you by.

Comment: How many users do you expect and what kind of activity do you expect? What storage engine are you using for `Users`?

Comment: @NickChammas: MyISAM, I thought about InnoDB but InnoDB has amazingly slow `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: @NickChammas: You mean to store ids in a flat file & updated once a minute for all users (`UPDATE Users SET timestamp = time() WHERE uid IN (ids, here)`) ? I currently do not expect activity on my own network, maybe after a few years, but I'd might want to sell it & I want to be sure it will be able to scale. If you have any tips, share them, please

Comment: Why do you care about the performance of `COUNT(*)`? What you want to handle is high concurrent activity against the `Users` table, and for that [you need InnoDB](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3804/2660).

Comment: And for the caching, I meant store the activity in something like Redis that you use as a cache and only periodically write it to the database. Do you really want to hit your database with a write every time a user does any kind of action?

Comment: @NickChammas: I don't, that's why I'm asking here

Comment: @NickChammas: `Why do you care about the performance of COUNT` because I will need COUNT(), and waiting +10 seconds for page load because I want number of users stored in DB in quite high

Comment: Why would it take 10 seconds or more to query for count? a) you don't need to query that for everyone, b) queries that take that long right now can be optimized to not take as long by a proper DBA in the future. c) redis is your better bet here. You don't really even need to store it in the database for long term, if they're not in redis, they're offline. If they are in redis, they're online. Easy enough, and keeps the frequently update information in memory (in caching, as it were).

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and easiest to scale query is the query you don't run.

- Move your session state to a cache tier like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/).
- Update the cached value on every user interaction, not the database value.
- Persist to the database via a background task that periodically scans the cache for updates.

Comment: Is it necessary to use memchached? Couldn't I use flat files & my own caching layer?

Comment: Why develop a caching solution when one already exists, that is well tested and proven to scale. I don't see how you can compare your flat file approach with a scale out solution like memcached.